# nfsroot freezing every once in a while presumably due to network glitch

Tags: linux, gentoo, nfs

**Setup**

I've set up a thin client running gentoo according to [these instructions](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Diskless_nodes). It seems to work quite nicely except that every once in a while it freezes.

I've found that I can duplicate the issue by pulling the network, running ls, and then plugging the network back in. For whatever reason it's not recovering from the loss of network. I would assume that the OS should be able to handle momentary I/O loss (let's say that a hard drive takes a second or two to respond), so I think it can't be just a glitch in the filesystem, but rather that the nfs connection isn't coming back at all. The filesystem is mounted as nfs4 with the following options:

```
rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=4096,wsize=4096,namlen=255,hard,proto=udp,port=0,timeo=11,retrans=3,sec=sys,clientaddr=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx,local_lock=none,addr=yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
```

<del>Previously, I was using no proto spec (defaulting to tcp) and that didn't work any better.</del> I've found that after removing the udp flag from boot it still boot as udp, so now I think I may have been looking at the `/home` mount instead of the `/` mount.

I figure what's happening when I'm not pulling the cord is that the network glitches for a second, something's trying to access a file (seems to be freezing when I'm compiling some software), and then it doesn't recover.

**Information from dmesg**

I have run a bunch of tests, and found that apparently disconnecting/reconnecting the cable doesn't always cause a problem, but sometimes does. In the dmesg log, when this happens, the last line is:

```
nfs: server yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy not responding, still trying
```

**Question**

What can I do to make the system robust to network problems?

Comment: NFS should resume working once the network comes back, so you should investigate the possibility that the network *isn't* coming back, due to hardware failure or some other cause.  Try pinging the server continuously and disconnecting/reconnecting your network cable.  If ping resumes working, you've ruled that out.

Comment: I can already tell you from prior experience that I can ping the system even after it's "frozen". So the network is definitely up.

Comment: More to add, I've replicated, by running ping before the connection is lost I can confirm that the client can ping the server and the server can ping the client after the connection loss/reconnection. Also I'm getting a message `nfs: server xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx not responding, still trying`, however it never seems to actually reconnect.

Comment: I just found out that perhaps I was never actually running in tcp mode (I booted up without the udp flag and it was still going udp, I had been looking at a different mount (the /home mount) which was getting mounted with tcp. Maybe that that was all that was up.